# zle backward-char not working as expected

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-zle

I'm writing a simple ZLE widget to quickly create subshells with `<C-j>`. Here's what I have:

```
function zle_subshell {
  zle -U '$()'
  zle .backward-char
}

# register as widget
zle -N zle_subshell

# create kbd
bindkey '^j' zle_subshell
```

However, it appears that `zle .backward-char` isn't working. What makes matters more confusing is that if I modify the script to be:

```
function zle_subshell {
  zle -U '$('
  zle -U ')'
  zle .backward-char
}
```

I get output like `)$(`...

It appears that `zle_subshell` function is being evaluated in reverse. Are there some obvious gotchas with ZLE widgets that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`zle -U`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle) usage is the pecial case. It seems that the behavior is intended:

> `zle -U string`
>   ...
>   This pushes the characters in the `string` onto the input stack of ZLE. After the widget currently executed finishes ZLE will behave as if the characters in the `string` were typed by the user.
>
> As ZLE uses a stack, if this option is used repeatedly the last string pushed onto the stack will be processed first. However, the characters in each `string` will be processed in the order in which they appear in the string.
>
> -- [`zshzle(1)`, ZLE BUILTINS, `zle -U`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle)

So, zsh will behave as if `)` and `$(` were typed after the `zle_subshell` finishes.

We could modify the [`(R)BUFFER`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-widgets_002c-user_002ddefined) to change the editor buffer directly like this:

```
function zle_subshell {
  RBUFFER='$()'"$RBUFFER"
  repeat 2 do zle .forward-char; done
  # ((CURSOR=CURSOR+2)) # We could do this instead.
}
```

Comment: I wonder what the rationale behind the stack implementation with `zle -U ...` is. Definitely unexpected behavior for my use-case.

Comment: I wonder, too. It seems that it had been added for just a fun according to [http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1999/msg02029.html](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1999/msg02029.html)

Comment: I've noticed that the url on my previous comment does not have proper reference link. So, I would like to post these urls for the record: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1999/msg02028.html http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1999/msg02029.html